# Smoothing calligraphy / script lines in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, image-trace

After you finish your custom script and have scan it to your computer to illustrator, how do you smooth the lines when vectorizing your script as if you have done it by hand? And how do you control the width of the lines?

[image]

Comment: Hi and wellcome to GD.SE. Your questin may be a bit too broad to give a satisfactory answer. You could narrow the question down. This site tends to deal with answerable bite sized and demonstrably correct answers.

Answer (score 1):

For smoothing I would recommend using the smooth pencil tool with a Wacom tablet if you have it.

The thickness will depend on how you are vectorizing. If you're outlining, there's not much else but to tweak the path. But if you're using strokes, through the centerline of the script, you can use the thickness tool to vary the stroke's width.